# Get command name inside hook closure

Tags: laravel, cron, hook, schedule

Consider the following code

```
$schedule->command('products:update')->name('Update products')->daily()->after(function() {
    // how do I get the name here?
});
```

How do I access the name of the command ("products:update" or "Update products") inside the closure?

Answer (score 0):

I think its work and in Kernel file on console.

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\PopulateGoogleService'
];

$schedule->command('PopulateGoogleService')->weekly()->sundays()->at('02:00')
            ->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
            ->sendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/cron.log'));
```